# Join two count query is not giving right result

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, count, union-all

I trying to join two query to compare count

```
SELECT count(customer_id) , customer_id
FROM `blog_post`
group by customer_id
```

and second query is

```
SELECT count(customer_id)
FROM `blog_comment`
WHERE `is_admin` IS NOT NULL
group by customer_id
```

Joined query i created is

```
SELECT count(post.customer_id) as post_count , post.customer_id ,
       count(comment.customer_id) 
FROM `blog_post` as post 
    left join blog_comment as comment on post.customer_id = comment.customer_id 
WHERE `is_admin` IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY post.customer_id
```

I am not getting the same result as running them individually , what am i doing wrong

Comment: A join is not appropriate here. I suggest a union all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement you need a `FULL OUTER JOIN` of the 2 queries, which is not supported by MySql and can only be simulated with `LEFT/RIGHT` joins and `UNION ALL`.

Another way to do what you want is to use `UNION ALL` for the 2 queries and aggregate on the results:

```
SELECT customer_id, 
       MAX(post_count) post_count,
       MAX(comment_count) comment_count 
FROM (
  SELECT customer_id, COUNT(*) post_count, 0 comment_count
  FROM `blog_post`
  GROUP BY customer_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT customer_id, 0, COUNT(*)
  FROM `blog_comment`
  WHERE `is_admin` IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY customer_id
) t
GROUP BY customer_id
```

Comment: if possible can you please explain query syntax , t is alias for ? and 0 after post count is for @forpas?

Comment: All subqueries/derived tables in MySql must be aliased. t is the alias of the subquery after FROM  clause of the main query.